# How to suppress Resharper VB.Net INTEGER_LITERAL expected error

Tags: vb.net, resharper

I would like to enable Solution Wide Analysis with Resharper. But Resharper incorrectly reports when using left aligned padding: "INTEGER_LITERAL expected"

It is a known issue at Jetbrains (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-477337)

I checked the documentation, but could not figure out how to suppress it.

```
' ReSharper disable once WhatsTheName
Console.WriteLine($"{foo,-15}")
```

Comment: I don't use ReSharper, but does [Change severity levels of code inspections](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__Configuring_Warnings.html#change_severity) help?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AndrewMorton, I can suppress it, but only supress it locally. I did not find a way to change level in a resharper setting or editorconfig. For solved by rewriting the code